# Is ar_internal_metadata table created in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm wondering if I need to create a migration for creating `ar_internal_metadata` in production on Rails 5

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's basically a safety switch, at the expense of complicating and changing how Rails apps are deployed:

> Rails 5 has added a new table `ar_internal_metadata` to store environment version which is used at the time of migrating the database.
>
> When the first time `rake db:migrate` is executed then new table stores the value `production`. Now whenever we load database schema or database structure by running rake `db:schema:load` or `rake db:structure:load` Rails will check if Rails environment is `production` or not. If not then Rails will raise an exception and thus preventing the data wipeout.

Source: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/07/rails-5-prevents-destructive-action-on-production-db.html

Comment: seen that page, missed that sentence...though I don't understand why this information is on a blog post and not in the Rails 5 release documentation.